# sorting collection linq query by parameter

Tags: c#, linq

There is a List, SomeObject has property TargetObject. 
I need is to create a List where SomeObjects have following TargetObject.

SO_1 (TO_1) | SO_2 (TO_2) | SO_3 (TO_3) | SO_4 (TO_1) | SO_5 (TO_1) | SO_6 (TO_1) | SO_7 (TO_1) | SO_8 (TO_2) | SO_9 (TO_2) | SO_10 (TO_4)

must be turned into

SO_1 (TO_1) | SO_2 (TO_2) | SO_3 (TO_3) | SO_10 (TO_4) | SO_4 (TO_1) | SO_8 (TO_2) | SO_6 (TO_1) | SO_9 (TO_2) | SO_7 (TO_1) | SO_5 (TO_1)

At the end i want to run Parallel.ForEach(List) with MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5, so each loop of 5 items will never have same TargetObject at the same time.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: I'm bad with rephrasing, collection from ... to is the best explanation i could make, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the `InterlaceBy` extension method I use for different purposes But it seems to apply to your case.

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() {1,2,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,4 }; //your TO's
var newlist = list.InterlaceBy(x => x).ToList(); //1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,1,1

public static partial class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> InterlaceBy<T, S>(this IEnumerable<T> input, Func<T, S> selector)
    {
        return input
              .GroupBy(selector)
              .SelectMany(g => g.Select((x, i) => new { key = i, value = x }))
              .OrderBy(x => x.key)
              .Select(x => x.value);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that (at least the easiest I could think of) is to first sort them by TargetObject, then group them by TargetObject and rebuild you collection using one element of each group at a time.

```
List<SomeObject> CustomSort( List<SomeObject> list)
{

  var ordered = list.OrderBy(x => x.TargetObject); // might not be necessary. Not sure if group by orders the group or not.
  var groups = ordered.GroupBy(x => x.x.TargetObject);
  List<SomeObject> res = new List<SomeObject>();

  int position = 0;
  while(res.Count < list.Count)
  {
    foreach (var grp in groups)
    {
        SomeObject current = grp.ElementAtOrDefault(position);
        if ( current != null) res.Add(current);
    }
    position ++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

PS: this code is not optimized, but is only meant to demonstrate the approach.